# Solve $C_N = (2 + 1/\log_2N)C_{N/2}$ for $N \ge2$ and $C_1 = 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Solve $C_N = (2 + 1/\log_2N)C_{N/2}$ for $N \ge2$ and $C_1 = 1$.

My solution:
$N = 2^n$

$C_{2^n} = 3*(5/2)*(7/3)*(9/4)*...*(2+1/n)$

$C_N = 3*(5/2)*...*(2+1/lgN)$

How can I simplify further?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly here (since you do not say), but anyway, $$C_{2^n}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n(n!)^2}$$

Comment: Simply rewrote your formula $C_{2^n} = 3*(5/2)*(7/3)*(9/4)*...*(2+1/n)$
 as a single ratio and multiplied by $2\cdot4\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n-2)(2n)=2^n\cdot n!$ both terms of the ratio.

Comment: ((Previous comment addresses a now deleted comment by the OP.))

Comment: Thank you, after a second look I realized your point of view, it s really simple!

Comment: Yes. Write an answer yourself then?

Comment: Hmm, sorry to disturb you once again, but:

Comment: $C_{2^n} = 3 * (5/2) * (7/3) * ... * (2 + 1/n)$ &\n&

$(2 + 1/n) = (2n + 1)/n$
or
$C_{2^n} = (3 * 5 * 7 * ... * (2n + 1)) / (1 * 2 * 3 ... * n)$
or
$C_{2^n} = (2n + 1)! / n!$

Comment: it feels like I was too optimistic with my understanding, from where came:
$1 / (2^n*(n!))$

Comment: No, $3\cdot5\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n+1)$ is not $(2n+1)!$, only $3\cdot5\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(2\cdot4\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n))$ is. And this is why the factor $2\cdot4\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)=2^n\cdot n!$ apears in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

$C_{2^n} = 3 * (5/2) * (7/3) * ... * (2 + 1/n)$
$(2 + 1/n) = (2n + 1)/n$
or
$C_{2^n} = (3 * 5 * 7 * ... * (2n + 1)) / (1 * 2 * 3 ... * n)$
or
$C_{2^n} = (2n + 1)! / ((2^n)* n! * n!)$